# Html Form-Get not responding

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a website for my company in MVC Razor3 .NET.
This is my first time working with MVC, but I've gained a lot of knowledge by now.
There is just one thing I can't seem to figure out.

I'm making a grading system for the manager of a service center who would like to grade the way his operators. When he graded an incident they are supposed to be be able to see the grade and fix the errors in the incident.If however they disagree with the grade received they have to be able to object and send a small comment along.

So in the review view for the operator (where he can either select fixed or to object) there is this code:

```
<tr class="border_bottom">
@if (false == Model.Fixed)
{

using (Html.BeginForm("Objected", "IncidentCheck", FormMethod.Get))
{
<td colspan=3>
<input id="Code" name="Code" type="hidden" value="@Model.Code" />
<input class="text-box single-line" style="width:100%" id="Message" name="Message" type="text"  value="" /> </td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Object" /></td>

}
}

</tr>
```

Which in time generates this Html:

```
<tr class="border_bottom">
<form action="/IncidentCheck/Objected" method="get"><td colspan=3>
<input id="Code" name="Code" type="hidden" value="C1308-0059" />
<input class="text-box single-line" style="width:100%" id="Message" name="Message" type="text"    value="" /> </td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Object" /></td>
</form>
</tr>
```

Now the display is perfect, but whenever I click the object button it simply refreshes the page without going to the correct action. The code of the action is useless for now, because it is never reached, but the function looks like this:

```
       [HttpGet]
    [RoleFilter(Roles = "Operator")] // Custom role filter.
    public ActionResult Objected (string Code, string Message)
    {

        return View("Test");
    }
```

Note: The HTML is part of a Displaytemplate in a partial view, so in the partial view there are more incidents who all have that same form. (not sure if that has got anything to do with it.)

I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking something simple.

Thanks in advance,
RoXaS

Comment: Could be that the browser isn't rendering the HTML in the way you expect because you've nested a `<form>` tag directly underneath a `<tr>` which isn't valid HTML. Can you wrap it around the entire table?

Comment: @RGraham Hmm that might actually work, Gonna try it now!

Comment: @RGraham on second thought, I can't because every 2 rows are another incident and they all need this from seperately. So I'm going to put in in just one table cell. EDIT: Did not work

Comment: Make sure that the routes in your RouteConfig.cs file are defined as expected. I'm working with MVC 4, so I'm not sure if the file layout will be the same.

Comment: @user65439 Routevalues are correct, I have made forms with get before, it just does not seem to redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops I made the accidental mistake of nesting forms, which is not allowed.

Found my mistake thanks to the users codebrain and Roel van Uden. Thank you guys for helping me answer this in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the HTML that is generated you can try to use the Razor syntax

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Objected, IncidentCheck, FormMethod.Get, 
           new { code= [Pass your code value here], 
                 message = [Pass your message value here] }))
{
     // Form elements.
}
```

instead of

```
<form action="/IncidentCheck/Objected" method="get">
    // Form elements.
</form>
```

Comment: But how is the message than dynamic, because I know the message value when the button is pushed, not when generating the html. If I knew that when generating the html i could have just used a link.

Comment: You should bind the message value to a parameter in your model, for example @Model.Message. You will then use your Razor syntax to bind Model.Message to a textbox in your form, for example @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Message). When submitting the form your model value would be set automatically based on the value of the textbox.